# How to call Azure Private Zone custom URLs points to AKS from App Service?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-aks

Previously have public domain with two subdomains created. Two API services on AKS points to these two subdomains and calling from App Services (UI application) via Nginx ingress controller. Everything as expected after Setup.

Now that public domain not renewed and expired. we don't want to use that public domain instead of that created Azure Private Zones with same URLs and pointed to AKS service and able to browse those two services from AKS. But same not working and throwing CORS Policy preflight and when I check in Network tab, seems its calling to that expired public domain Ip Address.

Please suggest. Appreciate your help here.

Thanks!!!

Expecting Azure Private Zone setup should call from App Service. Re-work application as usual.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs due to the expired public domain is still being called. Try to clear the DNS cache by using `ipconfig /flushdns`

In App service create private endpoint and vnet integration like below:

App service -> Networking -> Private endpoint create with express like below:

[image]

In private endpoint ensure to link your virtual network that contains your App Service and AKS cluster like below:

[image]

Update the DNS settings for your app service by updating the DNS records.

Updating the DNS records for your domain to point to the IP address of the Azure Private Zone in *DNS tab -> A record for your domain -> Update the IP address to point -> save*

[image]

In App service, under networking Add vnet integration to your outbound traffic with same virtual network like below:

[image]

Check if you can reach the DNS Server (defined in VNET) using  `tcpping <IP_DNS_Server>`   as below:

[image]

You can use the `nslookup` command from the Kudu console to check if the domain name is resolving to the correct IP address.

Now I am able to point my private zone to my app service Kudu console like below:

[image]

Once your App Service should be able to call the Azure Private Zone custom URLs points to AKS without any CORS Policy preflight issues.

Comment: we need to create new A record on Private DNS Zone of privatelink.azurewebsites.net with Load Balancer IP Address of Ingress controller then use subdomain of App service URL on Ingress YAML as Host? Please suggest.

Comment: Yaa correct @JaiHoDevs

Comment: I created A record api.<app service name> in privatelink.azurewebsites.net. When I do nslookup on Kudu like nslookup api.<app service name>.azurewebsites.net getting Unknown can't find : Non-existent domain

Please suggest